# Loading a class (.ps1 file) from network shared file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import a powershell class from a network shared file using the next command:

`."server\\scripts\powershellscripts\manager.ps1"`

And I get the next error:

"The given assembly name or codebase was invalid."

However If I move the file to a local drive like "C:\Intel\manager.ps1" (and change the path in the command of course) it does work.

Also, I have another .ps1 file in the same network file (same location) which I do manage to import using the exact same command above. Only difference is that this file is a functions file and not A class file

Helppp

Comment: Given the error you posted, it's likely that class file tries to add some sort of assembly (Add-Type). While class containing ps1 file itself may not be blocked by PowerShell execution policy on your computer from remote network share, there could be something in that the script. Does it have any sort of type loading in it?

Comment: It does not. No Add-type commands. It does however, use commands from modules which I added in the main file. (ActiveDirecory and psexcel modules)

Comment: Is it possible to show us the contents of the manager.ps1 file? Is it using Full (absolute) file paths for the modules it should load?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is classified so I can't. But as I said the manager.ps1 doesn't load anything, and the main program loads with full paths